# deploying a liberty war file to bluemix liberty gives error 400

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

After creating a WAR file using maven successfully, I tried uploading the WAR file to Liberty on Bluemix. I used the following command:

```
cf push wallet -p ./wallet-service/target/wallet-service-1.1-SNAPSHOT.war
Creating app wallet in org irazabal@us.ibm.com / space jax-rs as irazabal@us.ibm.com...
```

Got following response:

> "OK
>
> Creating route wallet.mybluemix.net...
> FAILED
> Server error, status code: 400, error code: 210003, message: The host is taken: wallet"

What does that mean and more importantly, how do you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The above error message means the hostname `wallet` is taken.  You are assigned a hostname on a shared domain of `mybluemix.net`.  You can fix this issue by choosing a unique name.  You can keep the name of the app to be `wallet` but choose a unique hostname with the following command.

```
cf push wallet -n somethingunique -p ./wallet-service/target/wallet-service-1.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

The `-n` argument allows to give a hostname to the app.

Additionally, you can point your own domain to Bluemix and use that with your app.